# User information in modal before submitting form in Yii

Tags: php, forms, yii, modal-dialog

I have a form and after user submits the form and validation goes OK, I want to ask him for his email and nickname in modal window. If user fills and submit an email and nickname, I want to validate it and save it as new record or get id of existing one (in case email was already used in past). If validation is not successful, user should be able to correct values in the same modal. If everything is OK, I want to save the form including create user id.

I already have form saving and user create/find process done. I just do not know, how to put this together, to work in scenario I described above. Could anyone explain, how this should be done in Yii? I am using Yii 1.1.15 and Yii Booster. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In Yii the `_form.php` view file is used both in `update.php` and `create.php` views by default.

So, you might need to do smth. similar: insert form with modal in both update.php and create.php views.
Actions and different for these, so you keep logic separate; this is the MVC basic advantage.

```
public function actionCreate() {
    $model = new Users;
    if (isset($_POST['Users'])) {
        $model->attributes = $_POST['Users'];
        if ($model->save()) { // here in the save() method the valadation is included
                              // ONLY after we validate and successfully saved we go to update action
                $this->redirect(array('update', 'id' => $model->id));
        }
    }
    $this->render('create', array(
        'model' => $model,
    ));
}
```

The main thing is that when you try to save [`save()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#save-detail) method the validation happend automatically.
So if validation is not successful the logic brings back to the same action (create for example) with fields populated in view since model is already having data passed into it: `$model->attributes = $_POST['Users']`.

If validation is successful we redirect further. Not nessesary ajax form submit, even casual submit fits here.

```
public function actionUpdate($id) {
    $model = $this->loadModel($id);
    if (isset($_POST['Users'])) {
        $model->attributes = $_POST['Users'];
        if ($model->save()) { // after saving EXISTING record we redirect to 'admin' action
                $this->redirect(array('admin'));
        }
    }
    $this->render('update', array(
        'model' => $model,
    ));
}
```

Forms in views(update/create) you keep as originally designed.

Validation for uniqueness is simple in model rules():

```
array('username, email', 'unique'),
```

Email valadation for email syntax is seems like this:

```
array('email', 'email'),
```

Comment: So the solution should be:
- Create form with Ajax submit
- If validation is ok, populate modal
- User enters email and nickname

What to do next? How do I validate email and nickname and then submit all data together?